# XSLT - Add new attributes and node

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a xml like follows,

```
<doc>
    <a type="atr111"></a>
    <a type="atr111"></a>
    <a type="atr111"></a>
    <a type="atr222"></a>
    <a type="atr222"></a>
    <a type="atr222"></a>
</doc>
```

my requirements are,

1. add dynamically increment `id` attribute to  nodes which has attribute `atr111` and `atr222`
2. add new node inside  nodes, named `<newNode>` having attribute `id="newAttr"` which has attribute `atr111` and `atr222`
3. change `<a>` nodes attribute value `atr111` to `atr222`.

so my expected output is,

```
<doc>
    <a id="id-1" type="atr222"><newNode id="newAttr"/></a>
    <a id="id-2" type="atr222"><newNode id="newAttr"/></a>
    <a id="id-3" type="atr222"><newNode id="newAttr"/></a>
    <a id="id-4" type="atr222"><newNode id="newAttr"/></a>
    <a id="id-5" type="atr222"><newNode id="newAttr"/></a>
    <a id="id-6" type="atr222"><newNode id="newAttr"/></a>
</doc>
```

the xsl I have written to get those output is follows,

```
<xsl:template match="a" priority="1">
        <!-- add new dynamic id -->
      <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="id">
                <xsl:value-of select="'id-'"/> 
                <xsl:number count="a[@type='atr111' or @type='atr222']" level="any"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:copy>

        <!-- add newNode inside <a> node -->
        <xsl:copy>
        <newNode>
            <xsl:attribute name="id">newAttr</xsl:attribute>
        </newNode>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- change existing 'atr111' attribute value to 'atr222' -->
    <xsl:template match="a/@type[. = 'atr111']">
        <xsl:attribute name="type">atr222</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
```

My current output comes as follows,

```
<doc>
    <a id="id-1"/><a><newNode id="newAttr"/></a>
    <a id="id-2"/><a><newNode id="newAttr"/></a>
    <a id="id-3"/><a><newNode id="newAttr"/></a>
    <a id="id-4"/><a><newNode id="newAttr"/></a>
    <a id="id-5"/><a><newNode id="newAttr"/></a>
    <a id="id-6"/><a><newNode id="newAttr"/></a>
</doc>
```

As you can see dynamic ids have added as expected, and `<newNode>` with new attribute has also added.but it has duplicated the `<a>` node. also existing attribute `type` has disappeared.

How can I organize my code to get the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to copy the `type` attribute. `<xsl:copy>` only copies the current node itself, not its children or attributes.

The following utilizes the identity template for the process of copying children and attributes.

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="a[@type='atr111' or @type='atr222']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="id">
                <xsl:text>id-</xsl:text>
                <xsl:number count="a[@type='atr111' or @type='atr222']" level="any" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
            <newNode id="newAttr" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Output:

```
<doc>
    <a id="id-1" type="atr111"><newNode id="newAttr"/></a>
    <a id="id-2" type="atr111"><newNode id="newAttr"/></a>
    <a id="id-3" type="atr111"><newNode id="newAttr"/></a>
    <a id="id-4" type="atr222"><newNode id="newAttr"/></a>
    <a id="id-5" type="atr222"><newNode id="newAttr"/></a>
    <a id="id-6" type="atr222"><newNode id="newAttr"/></a>
</doc>
```

You could of course also use `<xsl:copy-of select="@type" />` if there are no other children, but that's less flexible: Copying through the identity template enables you to carry over variable input and to add, for example, an `<xsl:template match="a/@type">` later-on that does some special processing to `@type` nodes, if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. :) It's working very well for may first 2 requirements, but as my 3rd requirement says I have to change <a> nodes attribute value atr111 to atr222. can I put that part of xsl to your written template. I've tried could not get a success result.

Comment: Read the last paragraph of my answer again. It will tell you what to do.